# InvalidQueryException despite having secondary index?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, database, nosql

I have a column family described as below.  I have secondary key for name column.

```
CREATE TABLE group (
      pid timeuuid,
      members map<bigint, boolean>,
      name text,
      PRIMARY KEY ((pid))
    ) WITH
      bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
      caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
      comment='' AND
      dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
      gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
      index_interval=128 AND
      read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
      replicate_on_write='true' AND
      populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
      default_time_to_live=0 AND
      speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
      memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
      compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
      compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};

    CREATE INDEX pidx ON group(name);
```

But `query` on equality on `name` column from java driver is giving me a

`com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator`

My query is as below. All search results in google are regarding either not having `secondary index` or using some non equality relational operators.

What is the reason for this error despite having secondary index?

Here is my query: `SELECT * FROM  group WHERE name ='Name'`

Update: The same schema works in my localhost cassandra server but not in server provided by our company.

In any case it's working from `cqlsh` window but in remote server's case it's not working through java datastax driver Other type of queries are working fine.

Thank you.

Comment: not even a comment? it seems....

Comment: I just followed your exact steps and it worked for me in cqlsh. Can you try the create index step again?

Comment: I've even tried this in my localhost server it's working.... but I'm in a work enivironment, I'm talking about a remote server provided by our company where the keyspaces are stored

Comment: It's happening for every column family, from cqlsh it's working but from java it's not working...

Comment: @BrianC Is there any chance it's because configuration in our company's cassandra's keyspaces?

Comment: Do you have `CREATE` permissions out on your work environment?

Comment: I hope yes. I created the table, above is the describe table version The task was assigned one. Other queries have worked for example  `select *` or `insert` statements.

Comment: Is the remote server cluster a single node or multiple nodes? It's possible (but not likely) that the index did not propagate correctly to all nodes, and that cqlsh and your Java app are connecting to separate nodes. Also, what version of the Java driver and Cassandra are being used, and are the local and remote versions of Cassandra the same?

Comment: As far as I can tell: Multiple nodes, driver version 2.1.0 (but I tried with new version with the same result). It happened for many column families others working on so may not be a incidental propagation issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran through your code. Created the table mentioned above (using copy-paste just to ensure that everything you did is correct), created the index. Everything works. This leads to one of two conclusions:

- The index creation failed leading to the error message you see. (my money is on this one...)
- You're possibly using the incorrect keyspace.

Comment: I've even tried this in my localhost server it's working.... but I'm in a work enivironment, I'm talking about a remote server provided by our company where the keyspaces are stored

Comment: The problem is same for all column spaces. If index creation is a problem I think it should not work from cqlsh client. It's working from cqlsh it's not working from java program.

Comment: @pinkpanther I'm thinking its a one off. Try re-creating the ks.cf pair with index on a test table to see what happens.